# What's the behavior of ${SOME_VAR+x} ? Could It fail in a .sh file?

Tags: bash, sh, eclipse-che

I'm debugging a `sh` script. What's the behavior of these lines of code?

```
SOME_VAR=$(env)

if [ ! -z ${SOME_VAR+x} ]; then
    echo "SOMETHING HAPPENED "
fi
```

What does `+x` mean in this case? It turns out that code works fine with `bash`, but no with `sh`.

**EDIT:** I'm working with the deployment of an Eclipse Che local instance like it's explained [here](https://www.eclipse.org/che/getting-started/download/).

I installed the Eclipse Che CLI that is a .sh script:

```
$ curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/che/master/che.sh > /usr/local/bin/che
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/che
```

To make it work, I need to run it using `bash`:

```
$ bash che start
```

If I debug the script...

```
$ sh -x che start
```

The script fails here:

```
get_list_of_che_system_environment_variables() {

    [...]

    if [ ! -z ${CHE_VARIABLES+x} ]; then
      env | grep CHE_ >> $DOCKER_ENV
      RETURN=$DOCKER_ENV
    fi
```

Something is not working. If you say the substitution should work in .sh too, what would be the problem?

Comment: The code should work identically in any POSIX-compatible shell.

Comment: What means that the code doesn't work with `sh`? All the commands are valid in `sh`.

Comment: @redmm I edited my question to show you what could be the problem

Answer (score 2):

`${SOME_VAR+x}` expands to the empty string if `SOME_VAR` is not set. If it is set (even to the empty string), it expands to `x`.

Since `SOME_VAR` was set on the previous line, it will *always* expand to `x`. This makes the `if` statement irrelevant, as the code will always output `SOMETHING HAPPENED`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a form of parameter substitution which will yield `x` if `SOME_VAR` is set, or a null String if it isn't.

You can learn more about the different type of parameters substitution [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).